# about closed linear subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, hilbert-spaces

Can you help me, plese, with the notion of **closed linear subspace**. What means, examples of closed linear subspace, how can I prove that a subspace is a closed linear subspace.

Thanks :-)

Comment: Where? In a normed vector space?

Comment: @julien Hilbert spaces!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A linear subspace $V$ of a Hilbert space $H$ is called closed it is closed with respect to the norm topology: i.e. whenever $(v_n)$ in $V$ converges to $h$ ($\| v_n-h\|\rightarrow 0$) in $H$, then $h$ belongs to $V$.

Examples: any finite-dimensional subspace is closed, any orthogonal $A^\perp$ is a closed linear subspace.

Counter-example: if $(e_n)$ is a Hilbert basis of an infinite-dimensional separable Hilbert space $H$, then $V=Vect((e_n))$ is a linear subspace of $H$ which fails to be closed.